# in respect of vs. in respect to

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> in respect of vs. in respect to

I saw 'in respect of' a lot but didn't see 'in respect to'.

'in respect to' is also possible to mean 'about'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+respect+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that *in respect to* was much more common in the 19th century than it is now. Today we usually say '**with** respect to'.